# How can I make videos load after clicking play not before?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, flash

How can I make videos load after clicking play not before?
and 
what is the best way, using HTML5 video tag or make a flash player?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **preload** attribute in HTML video element. Enable the option after play is clicked using jquery.

Answer (score 1):

You can pause a video using the pause() method:

```
$("#videoID").get(0).pause();
```

You can then resume the playback of the video using the play() method:

```
$("#videoID").get(0).play();
```